# Calling Module URLs gives 404, action is always "noRoute"

Tags: magento-1.7, module

I am creating my own module, and on very beginning I stuck on some problem. Calling controller actions through URL don't work.

**app/etc/modules/Locatores_CpCode.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Locatores_CpCode>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Locatores_CpCode>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Locatores/CpCode/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Locatores_CpCode>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Locatores_CpCode>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <cpcode>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Locatores_CpCode</module>
                    <frontName>cpcode</frontName>
                </args>
            </cpcode>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Locatores/CpCode/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class Locatores_CpCode_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        die("whatever");
    }
}
```

I try to access my module through:

- www.myshop.com/cpcode/index
- www.myshop.com/index.php/cpcode
- www.myshop.com/index.php/cpcode/index
- www.myshop.com/index.php/cpcode/index/index

Through Xdebug I see that requested **URL**s are entering in **IndexController**, but action is always **"noRoute"**.

If I hardcode *$action* variable in core for example:

```
$active = 'index';
```

Then controller action is triggered successfully, but of course that is no solution.

Comment: Try to clean cache

Comment: tried, still not work :(

Comment: Your code is correct.  Please check that your module is available on magento. Got to admin panel. System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced and check that module Locatores_CpCode is enabled. 
Maybe you use not latin codex. For example some symbols from cyrilic codex.

Comment: I see my module in System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced, but still noRoute  :(